# How to plot a right triangle path in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, robotics

The following code is used to plot a circular path:

```
% Head velocity
v = 1.5;
% Angular velocity
w = 1;      
% Radius
R = v/w;
% Time
dt = 0.1;
t = 0:dt:(2*pi*R/v);
% Initial mobile robot position vector
x0 = 0; y0 = 0; th0 = 0;
P = [];
P(:,1) = [x0 y0 th0]; 
% Loop for all time steps
for k = 1 : length(t)
    P(:,k+1) = P(:,k) + dt*[v*cos(P(3,k));v*sin(P(3,k));w];
    plot(P(1,1:k+1),P(2,1:k+1))
    pause(0.01)
    axis square
    axis([-2 2 -0.5 3.5])
end
```

, how can I manipulate the position vector to plot a right triangle path.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A triangle is made of three lines, so instead of the equation of a point on a circumference (`v*cos(...), v*sin(...)`) use the equation of a point on a straigth line. You'll probably have to keep track of the length travelled along each segment, and switch to a new line (the new side) once the cumulated length is equal to the side length.

Comment: @MatteoV
The plot needs to be in terms of `v*cos(...),v*sin(...)` , I think of making 3 "for" loops for each segment.

Comment: No, that's wrong. cosine and sine are **ONLY** used for **CIRCULAR** trajectories, you need three equations for **LINEAR** trajectories.